# How to check efficiently, if a substring exists : SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to do certain actions based on the decision if a sub string exists in a column.

For example my column 'LangCodes' have # separated values like en-us#ar-ae#in-id.

I can use the SQL **in** operator if I can convert the value in form like : 'en-us','ar-ae','in-id'.

For example `select Col1 from Table1 where 'en-us' in (LangCodes)`

Do I need to use replace function of SQL to accomplish this or any better way exists?

Comment: How about `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE LANGCODES LIKE '%en-us%'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this efficiently in SQL Server, because you are storing your data in a fashion not consistent with the use of relational databases.  You need a separate correlation table that has columns `id` and `LangCode`, with one row per language code.

You *can* do what you want with string operations.  Here is a typical way:

```
where '#'+LangCodes+'#' like '%#en-us#%'
```

This, however, cannot take advantage of an index on `LangCodes`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It helped me to eliminate 3 OR conditions. i.e. : select Col1 from Table1 where LangCodes = 'en-us' OR  LangCodes like '%#en-us#%' OR  LangCodes like '%en-us#%' OR  LangCodes like '%#en-us%'

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient and best way to check your languages codes is to seperate them in your table.

#### Never, never, never store multiple values in one column!

This is how your tables could look like (just examples)

```
product table
-------------
id
name

language_code table
-------------------
id 
name

product_language_code table
---------------------------
product_id
language_code_id
```

Comment: I understand that we should not store multiple values in one column, but what if these values are coming from a Legacy Database & we dont have any control on how to store these values?

Comment: Then use Gordons answer